# Data Modeling issue with Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I am extremely new to Neo4j but it has got me excited. However, I am facing a difficulty in trying to model the following data which is in the form of a CSV file.

```
ID      Document    Word
123     Book        Potter,Love,Bond
124     Book        Love,Game
134     Pad         Game,Hate
111     BB          Hate,Level,Awesome
109     Feat        Awesome
```

Ideally I am looking to have ID as unique element of each node, Document column as one of the node property and all the words as individual nodes attached to each ID with a relationship HAS. So Love would be related to both IDs 123 and 124

Any help on the cypher query would be great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create a constraint on the document node and word node

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (d:Document) ASSERT d.id IS UNIQUE

CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (w:Word) ASSERT d.name IS UNIQUE
```

im guessing you are using `LOAD CSV`

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "url" as row
MERGE (d:Document{id:row.ID})
ON CREATE SET d.type = row.Document
with d,split(row.Word,",") as words
UNWIND words as word    
MERGE (w:Word{name:word})
MERGE (d)-[:HAS]->(w)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just a couple of things, that must be typos. But I am unable to resolve the errors due to them

1. The second CREATE constraint statement seems to need w.name instead of d.name

2. The MERGE (d:Document{row.ID}) statement is giving me an error "No viable alternative at input...."

Looking at the next merge I replaced rows with id. But this threw another error as follows:
 
"Variable `id` not defined (line 2, column 21 (offset: 60))
"MERGE (d:Document{d:id})".

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: edited the answer... cypher is fine, just depends what your csv looks like